# Sending data via Flutter's platform channel is too slow

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I'm utilizing Flutter's platform channel to send a 'huge' pile of data from the Dart side to Java.
It's a **Float32List** consisting of 393216 elements, so roughly 1.6 Megabyte.

On the Dart side I'm using the following function to send the data:

```
  Future<Null> sendData(Float32List data) {
_channel.invokeMethod('sendData', {'data': data});
    return null;
  }
```

and the Java side handles the incoming message like this:

```
  @Override
  public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull Result result) {

    Map<String, ?> arguments = (Map<String, ?>) call.arguments;
    if (call.method.equals("sendData")) {
}
}
```

So at the moment nothing more than mapping the MethodCall's arguments to a HashMap.

Anyway, this data needs to be transferred each frame e.g. every 16 milliseconds.
Unfortunately the framerate drops significantly from 60 to around 20 fps.
Examining the logs it seems that part of the problem seems to be the garbage collector which constantly kicks in to free up memory.

```
I/send_data( 6306): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/send_data( 6306): Background concurrent copying GC freed 1(15KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 165MB/171MB, paused 477us total 675.471ms
I/send_data( 6306): WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on ProfileSaver for 256.348ms
I/flutter ( 6306): FPS 21.1287106362165615
I/send_data( 6306): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/send_data( 6306): Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 4665422(89MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(72MB) LOS objects, 50% free, 4MB/8MB, paused 439us total 28.436ms
I/send_data( 6306): Background concurrent copying GC freed 53274(859KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 59MB/65MB, paused 995us total 116.669ms
I/send_data( 6306): Background concurrent copying GC freed 0(30KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 84MB/90MB, paused 417us total 1.021s
I/send_data( 6306): Background concurrent copying GC freed 83319(1317KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 132MB/138MB, paused 2.752ms total 1.096s
I/flutter ( 6306): FPS 21.1287106362165615
I/send_data( 6306): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/send_data( 6306): Background concurrent copying GC freed 2253876(43MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(36MB) LOS objects, 6% free, 86MB/92MB, paused 916us total 312.417ms
I/send_data( 6306): WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on HeapTrim for 53.920ms
I/send_data( 6306): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/send_data( 6306): Background concurrent copying GC freed 2429155(46MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(36MB) LOS objects, 9% free, 55MB/61MB, paused 1.316ms total 227.108ms
I/flutter ( 6306): FPS 21.1287106362165615
I/flutter ( 6306): FPS 21.0497952899184655
I/send_data( 6306): Background concurrent copying GC freed 35649(581KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 75MB/81MB, paused 2.148ms total 778.779ms
I/Choreographer( 6306): Skipped 418 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/flutter ( 6306): FPS 20.9614768284084351
I/send_data( 6306): Background concurrent copying GC freed 1(18KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 84MB/90MB, paused 3.093ms total 820.288ms
I/flutter ( 6306): FPS 20.9112724400838368
```

probably because on the Java side for every call it allocates new memory for the incoming data.

So I'm asking myself is the above the correct way of doing this or is there another method to do this more efficiently? Is there a way to share a specific memory region where the Dart as well as the Java side have read/write access without using the platform channel?

## Update

It runs a whole lot better if using a **Float64List** instead of Float32List. I'm not sure if it's an advantage though since all the double values need to be converted to floats on the Java side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is way but not the best. My solution is save data in storage using dart and through java read the file do operations and save it. Finally read the new data from storage of phone.